# Grey Screen in Java Netbeans - How do I prevent this?

Tags: java, netbeans, jframe, rendering, screen

I am currently using NetBeans IDE with JFrame.
On the IDE, the screen renders fine. 
See attached screenshot.[Working Screen Rendered by Netbeans IDE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4mxJd.png)

However, when I run the file, I am presented with a grey screen.
See attached screenshot. [Grey Screen Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cZ8Kh.png)

The following is the code:

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package groupchatapp;

/**
 *
 * @author Jim Ng
 */
public class ChatInterface extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    /**
     * Creates new form GroupChatGUI
     */


    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        TalkIcon = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        TalkIcon1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        usersLbl = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        GroupsLbl = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        GroupChatsLbl = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        groupNameLbl = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        groupLblWhiteBg = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        userLblWhiteBg = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        groupsScrollPane = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
        groupChatList = new java.awt.List();
        groupNameScrollPane = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
        allMessagesTextField = new java.awt.TextField();
        viewBtn = new java.awt.Button();
        deleteChatBtn = new java.awt.Button();
        editChatBtn = new java.awt.Button();
        createNewBtn = new java.awt.Button();
        typeMessageTextField = new java.awt.TextField();
        sendBtn1 = new java.awt.Button();
        addBtn1 = new java.awt.Button();
        GardensByTheBayBG = new javax.swing.JLabel();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        getContentPane().setLayout(null);

        TalkIcon.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 255));
        TalkIcon.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 255));
        TalkIcon.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/groupchatapp/TalkIcon.png"))); // NOI18N
        getContentPane().add(TalkIcon);
        TalkIcon.setBounds(310, 0, 190, 200);

        TalkIcon1.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 255));
        TalkIcon1.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 255));
        TalkIcon1.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/groupchatapp/GroupIcon.png"))); // NOI18N
        TalkIcon1.setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(30, 30));
        getContentPane().add(TalkIcon1);
        TalkIcon1.setBounds(250, 210, 50, 50);

        usersLbl.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 255));
        usersLbl.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 0, 36)); // NOI18N
        usersLbl.setHorizontalAlignment(javax.swing.SwingConstants.CENTER);
        usersLbl.setText("Users");
        getContentPane().add(usersLbl);
        usersLbl.setBounds(610, 210, 130, 50);

        GroupsLbl.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 255));
        GroupsLbl.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 0, 36)); // NOI18N
        GroupsLbl.setHorizontalAlignment(javax.swing.SwingConstants.CENTER);
        GroupsLbl.setText("Groups");
        getContentPane().add(GroupsLbl);
        GroupsLbl.setBounds(70, 200, 160, 70);

        GroupChatsLbl.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 255));
        GroupChatsLbl.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 0, 36)); // NOI18N
        GroupChatsLbl.setHorizontalAlignment(javax.swing.SwingConstants.CENTER);
        GroupChatsLbl.setText("Group Name");
        getContentPane().add(GroupChatsLbl);
        GroupChatsLbl.setBounds(240, 200, 370, 70);

        groupNameLbl.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 255));
        groupNameLbl.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 255));
        groupNameLbl.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/groupchatapp/WhiteBackground.PNG"))); // NOI18N
        groupNameLbl.setText("Ty");
        getContentPane().add(groupNameLbl);
        groupNameLbl.setBounds(240, 210, 360, 50);

        groupLblWhiteBg.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 255));
        groupLblWhiteBg.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 255));
        groupLblWhiteBg.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/groupchatapp/WhiteBackground.PNG"))); // NOI18N
        groupLblWhiteBg.setText("Ty");
        getContentPane().add(groupLblWhiteBg);
        groupLblWhiteBg.setBounds(70, 210, 160, 50);

        userLblWhiteBg.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 255));
        userLblWhiteBg.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 255));
        userLblWhiteBg.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/groupchatapp/WhiteBackground.PNG"))); // NOI18N
        userLblWhiteBg.setText("Ty");
        getContentPane().add(userLblWhiteBg);


   userLblWhiteBg.setBounds(610, 210, 130, 50);

    groupsScrollPane.setViewportView(groupChatList);

    getContentPane().add(groupsScrollPane);
    groupsScrollPane.setBounds(70, 270, 160, 230);

    allMessagesTextField.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Dialog", 0, 24)); // NOI18N
    groupNameScrollPane.setViewportView(allMessagesTextField);

    getContentPane().add(groupNameScrollPane);
    groupNameScrollPane.setBounds(240, 270, 360, 190);

    viewBtn.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(255, 0, 0));
    viewBtn.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Dialog", 0, 24)); // NOI18N
    viewBtn.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 255));
    viewBtn.setLabel("View");
    getContentPane().add(viewBtn);
    viewBtn.setBounds(630, 460, 90, 40);

    deleteChatBtn.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(255, 0, 0));
    deleteChatBtn.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 255));
    deleteChatBtn.setLabel("Delete");
    getContentPane().add(deleteChatBtn);
    deleteChatBtn.setBounds(120, 540, 70, 20);

    editChatBtn.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(255, 0, 0));
    editChatBtn.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 255));
    editChatBtn.setLabel("Edit");
    editChatBtn.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            editChatBtnActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });
    getContentPane().add(editChatBtn);
    editChatBtn.setBounds(160, 510, 70, 20);

    createNewBtn.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(255, 0, 0));
    createNewBtn.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 255));
    createNewBtn.setLabel("Create");
    createNewBtn.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            createNewBtnActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });
    getContentPane().add(createNewBtn);
    createNewBtn.setBounds(70, 510, 70, 20);

    typeMessageTextField.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Dialog", 0, 24)); // NOI18N
    typeMessageTextField.setText("type your message here...");
    getContentPane().add(typeMessageTextField);
    typeMessageTextField.setBounds(240, 460, 360, 40);

    sendBtn1.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(255, 0, 0));
    sendBtn1.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Dialog", 0, 24)); // NOI18N
    sendBtn1.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 255));
    sendBtn1.setLabel("Send");
    getContentPane().add(sendBtn1);
    sendBtn1.setBounds(510, 510, 90, 40);

    addBtn1.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(255, 0, 0));
    addBtn1.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Dialog", 0, 24)); // NOI18N
    addBtn1.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 255));
    addBtn1.setLabel("Add");
    getContentPane().add(addBtn1);
    addBtn1.setBounds(410, 510, 90, 40);

    GardensByTheBayBG.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/groupchatapp/Singapore Garden City.jpg"))); // NOI18N
    getContentPane().add(GardensByTheBayBG);
    GardensByTheBayBG.setBounds(0, -210, 2260, 1090);

    pack();
}// </editor-fold>                        

private void createNewBtnActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                             
    // TODO add your handling code here:
}                                            

private void editChatBtnActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            
    // TODO add your handling code here:
}                                           

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String args[]) {
    /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
    //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
    /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
     * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
     */
    try {
        for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
            if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                break;
            }
        }
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(ChatInterface.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(ChatInterface.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(ChatInterface.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(ChatInterface.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    //</editor-fold>
    //</editor-fold>
    //</editor-fold>
    //</editor-fold>

    /* Create and display the form */
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new ChatInterface().setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}

// Variables declaration - do not modify                     
private javax.swing.JLabel GardensByTheBayBG;
private javax.swing.JLabel GroupChatsLbl;
private javax.swing.JLabel GroupsLbl;
private javax.swing.JLabel TalkIcon;
private javax.swing.JLabel TalkIcon1;
private java.awt.Button addBtn1;
private java.awt.TextField allMessagesTextField;
private java.awt.Button createNewBtn;
private java.awt.Button deleteChatBtn;
private java.awt.Button editChatBtn;
private java.awt.List groupChatList;
private javax.swing.JLabel groupLblWhiteBg;
private javax.swing.JLabel groupNameLbl;
private javax.swing.JScrollPane groupNameScrollPane;
private javax.swing.JScrollPane groupsScrollPane;
private java.awt.Button sendBtn1;
private java.awt.TextField typeMessageTextField;
private javax.swing.JLabel userLblWhiteBg;
private javax.swing.JLabel usersLbl;
private java.awt.Button viewBtn;
// End of variables declaration
```

}

May I know what is the issue with my code and why am I rendered with a grey screen when I run the file?

I am on NetBeans 10.0.2 and this is done using JFrame.

Comment: I looked like 7-10 times and while I may overlook it, I think the constructor is missing, that calls initComponents(). Netbeans is able to render something as it stores the information in an additional xml. But if you run the code you actually need to call the initComponents() - most likely from the(a) constructor, that seems missing.

Comment: @kai that worked. Thanks, mate.